# How to create a dictionary containing lambda expressions using comprehension list?

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, list-comprehension

I am trying to generate (something like) the following dictionary:

```
funcs1 = {
    '0':lambda x:x==0,
    '1':lambda x:x==1,
    '2':lambda x:x==2,
    '3':lambda x:x==3,
    '4':lambda x:x==4,
    '5':lambda x:x==5,
}
```

I tried to create the dictionary with a list comprehension like this:

```
funcs2 = {str(i):lambda x:x==i for i in range(0,6)}
```

Or simply using a for loop:

```
funcs3 = {}
for i in range(0,6):
    funcs3.update({str(i): lambda x:x==i})
```

However, `funcs2` and `funcs3` are not the same as `funcs1`, for example, when calling the element `'0'` of each one of them and applying it to `0`, the results are different:

```
funcs1['0'](0)
Out[2]: True

funcs2['0'](0)
Out[3]: False

funcs3['0'](0)
Out[4]: False
```

Can somebody please help me out and point out where I am making a mistake?

Comment: https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common misunderstanding caused by Python [late binding](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#late-binding-closures), this should fix your code:

```
funcs1 = {
    '0': lambda x: x == 0,
    '1': lambda x: x == 1,
    '2': lambda x: x == 2,
    '3': lambda x: x == 3,
    '4': lambda x: x == 4,
    '5': lambda x: x == 5,
}

funcs2 = {str(i): lambda x, i=i: x == i for i in range(0, 6)}

funcs3 = {}
for i in range(0, 6):
    funcs3.update({str(i): lambda x, i=i: x == i})

print(funcs1['0'](0))
print(funcs2['0'](0))
print(funcs3['0'](0))
```

**Output**

```
True
True
True
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
>>> def make_fn(i):
...     def fn(x):
...         return x==i
...     return fn
...
>>> funcs = {str(i): make_fn(i) for i in range(6)}
```

Testing, I get:

```
>>> funcs['0'](0)
True
>>> funcs['1'](1)
True
>>> funcs['0'](1)
False
```